# How to use xmodmap to map Right-Alt to Super (Windows) key?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, xmodmap

I'm stuck trying to map Right-Alt to the Super ("Windows") key; I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

The keyboard I'm trying to use is an IBM Space Saver Keyboard ("SSK", 84 key ANSI layout, no "Windows" or "Menu" keys).

I've got this far with my .Xmodmap file:

```
! Right-Alt remapped to Super_L
clear mod4
keycode 108 = Super_L Super_L Super_L Super_L
add mod4 = Super_L
```

But I can't get the the SSK key (Alt_R) to behave like a real Windows key on a keyboard that has one.

With the .Xmodmap file above, when I click the Windows key on a USB keyboard that has one (and works OK), I get this from `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x20e, subw 0x0, time 3892681, (80,-9), root:(2551,614),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 108
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x20e, subw 0x0, time 3892785, (80,-9), root:(2551,614),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 108
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    atom 0x1c5 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 3892816, state PropertyNewValue
```

***The KDE menu pops up when I release the key.*** (As expected and desired.)

On my IBM SSK I get this (clicking Alt-Right):

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x20e, subw 0x0, time 3669990, (125,127), root:(2596,750),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x20e, subw 0x0, time 3670286, (125,127), root:(2596,750),
    state 0x40, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

***Nothing happens when I press or release the key.***

I tried it with Super_R as well - same result.

What am I doing wrong?